How to determine the twiddle factor in a mixed-radix FFT？
For example, for a 6-point FFT, I want to first calculate 3 sets of 2-point FFT, multiply the result by the "twiddle factor", and then perform 2 sets of 3-point FFT to get the final result.How to determine the "twiddle factor?
mixed-radix fft
this is my matlab code
leng = 6;

x = zeros(1, leng, 'single');

for i = 1:leng
    x(i) = single(i - 1);
end

A = zeros(1, leng,'single');

Wn = single(exp(-2*pi*1i*(0:leng-1)/leng));    % twiddle factor


% 0 2 4
% 1 3 5
radius = 1;
N = 2; 
group = 3;       

for  i = 0:group - 1        
    for j = 1:radius 
        index1 = j + i * N;  
        index2 = j + i * N + radius;
        [A(index1),A(index2)] = BF(x(index1),x(index2));
    end
end

% My question is here,Which numbers are multiplied by the twiddle factor?
A(4) = twiddle(A(4),Wn(2));
% A(5) = twiddle(A(5),Wn(3));
A(6) = twiddle(A(6),Wn(3));


% 0 1
% 2 3
% 4 5

radius = 2;
N = 3; 
group = 1;       

for  i = 0:group - 1        
    for j = 1:radius 
        index1 = j + i * N;  
        index2 = j + i * N + radius;
        index3 = i * N + 2 * radius + j;
        [A(index1),A(index2),A(index3)] = BF3(A(index1),A(index2),A(index3)); 
    end
end

  
A = bitReverse(A,leng);

